# Offline hotword detection API in Android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Android [has voice recognition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) APIs built in, and if you are lucky, you can even get them to work offline.  At any rate, using the SpeechRecognizer will get you a fairly turn-key solution for voice recognition.

However, I'm interested in implementing a Google Now style "hotword" (as in "OK, Google") that activates proper voice recognition.  This hotword needs to be always-on, and for the sake of the battery and the user's wireless bill, it shouldn't use the network.  In other words, **how do I replicate Google Now's hotword functionality?**

Comment: You can use CMUSphinx, see the demo here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: I tried out CMUSphinx, it turns out you would be bloating the apk size additionally to around 10 MB & the detection was more of a hit or miss. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.  Let me know if you work something out.

Comment: You can also look into https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/tree/master/examples/Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Porcupine](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine)? The [service demo](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/android/Service) is what you need for always-listening wake word detection.

Comment: Nice thank you! This did not exist when I asked the question. For lack of (any) alternatives, I will accept your answer :)